# Url Not Display Category Name

Tags: magento

When i navigate products, at status bar my url not display category name.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. In fact you haven't even asked a question. Perhaps you should rephrase it as a question and post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For My knowledge it's mostly the problem with reindexing. once you complete the reindexing to `Ready mode` , this problem may solve , including `catalog` url rewrites also should be in `Ready mode`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea,,

Comment: still my catalog_url_rewrite, catalog_search_index processing, when it will be completed, in my store  30,000 products are there,.

Comment: are you trying to reindex through backend or through ssh ?

Comment: through backend, how can i run ssh

Comment: if you use ssh also , i dont think it will work for you.... we use ssh to do reindexing fast , for my knowledge you need to find solution for [this](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=cz-8V9TcAfGK8QfT2pPoCg&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento%20catalog%20url%20rewrites%20index%20stuck%20on%20processing)

Comment: problem solved, after complete reindex all, error solved

Comment: @JeevaRathinam good job buddy, please upvote it if you like the answer...

Comment: already upvote ur answer bro, why the count is not increased mean, already you have one downvote from unknown,